# How can I suppress *:// from tab completion suggestions for 'open'?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, macos

I have experience this in `OS X` in `zsh` shell, [man page for open](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/open/).

```bsh
$ type open
open is /usr/bin/open

$ man open
  OPEN(1)                   General Commands
Manual                            OPEN(1)

NAME
     open – open files and directories
```

When I type `open` and type tab I see following output:

```bsh
$ open                                                                                                                          
file:      ftp://     gopher://    http://    https://
```

---

I never attempt to open any of `file:`, `ftp://`, `gopher://`,    `http://`, `https://`, hence I just want to suppress them. Is it possible to suppress them and only see the file/folder names.

Comment: `open` is not a bash built-in nor is `/usr/bin/open` part of any package I can find. So, um, you will have to tell us what `open` is, where it came from, and possibly, what provides the autocompletion for it! A good start would be to tell us the output of `type open`! Your question is also lacking info on your platform. What's your OS/distro/…?

Comment: In ubuntu https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man2/open.2.html  // in macOS seems like its builtin command. I am using `zsh` shell seems like it suggest autocompletions for it

Comment: You're confusing things! That's a man page for a libc call. you can use that from the C programming language, it's not something present in a shell!

Comment: Wait, you#re using `zsh` but tagged this [tag:bash]... also, still missing the output of `type open`!

Comment: I am using `open` in macOS , seems like its a builtin command.

Comment: it's not a builtin command, as type says: it's an executable in /usr/bin/open!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your output, `open` is an executable in your OS X system.

So, to modify its completion syntax, you'd need to figure out where the completion function resides and modify it (I have not been able to figure out how to remove things from completion lists in any way that is comparable in complexity to just modifying the existing function).

Use `whence -v $_comps[open]` to figure out where the completion function for `open` is defined. Copy that file somewhere you can find it, say /home/alper/bin/open_completion.zsh.

There, look for the line that calls the `_urls` function (which happens to be the completion argument function that offers `file:      ftp://     gopher://    http://    https://`).  It might look something like `'*:URL:_urls'` in a list of viable arguments.

You might to remove that statement.

Then, add that function to be loaded in your zshrc.